# passing 'const FunctionSet' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] on my type

Tags: c++, iterator, constants

I have defined type Functions and I have written method to convert this type to pair.
Definition:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::pair<int,FunctionPtr>> Functions;
```

FunctionPtr and FunctionId:

```
typedef int(*FunctionPtr) (const std::vector<cv::Mat>&, cv::Mat&);
struct FunctionId
{
    std::string name;
    int nArguments;
};
```

My method:

```
pair<FunctionId,FunctionPtr> FunctionSet::conversion(Functions::const_iterator& it)
{
    string name = it->first;
    int argumentsNumber = it->second.first;
    FunctionPtr function = it->second.second;
    FunctionId id = {name, argumentsNumber};

    return make_pair(id,function);
}
```

Then I call it here:

```
pair<FunctionId,FunctionPtr> FunctionSet::getRandomFunction() const
{
    Functions::const_iterator it = functions_.begin();
    std::advance(it, rand() % functions_.size() );

    pair<FunctionId,FunctionPtr> p = conversion(it); //in this line error

    return p;
}
```

And got error:

> passing 'const FunctionSet' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers
>   [-fpermissive]

```
note:   in call to 'std::pair<FunctionId, int (*)(const std::vector<cv::Mat>&, cv::Mat&)> FunctionSet::conversion(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::pair<int, int (*)(const std::vector<cv::Mat>&, cv::Mat&)> >::const_iterator)'              std::pair<FunctionId,FunctionPtr> conversion(Functions::const_iterator it);

                                   ^
```

FunciontSet is a class name.

Comment: Unlike `getRandomFunction`, `conversion` is not `const`.

Comment: Thanks. That's right. When i look for error I just focus on arguments and forgot about that.